# Multi-Class Document Classification with both known and un-known classes

Tags: nlp, multiclass-classification, unsupervised-learning, text-classification

Currently, I am building a multi-class document classifier which has to classify either 3 known classes, namely "Financial Report", "Insurance_Sheet", "Endorsement", and an unknown class namely "Random PDFs".

For document embedding, I create pipeline [TfidfVectorizer + SVD (for dimensional reduction)] and fitting on the training set (without unknown-labeled documents, or documents of "Random PDFs" class) and then using that Pipeline to transform for all the documents.

For classification is divided into 2 stages:

- Stage 1: Segregate the unknown and known-labeled documents using One-Class SVM for anomaly detection. Ideally, unknown document will be binned out for manual labeling, and the known-labeled documents will be transfer to stage 2.
- Stage 2: Training Multi-Class (3 classes) Classifier for the known-labeled documents. This works well with Linear SVC.

My problem is in Stage 1,  the unknown document is not able to be detected as outlier (or un-known label), but all of the unknown documents are classified as "known label" by One-Class SVM. Further error analysis, I realize that my unknown documents are Shareholder Announcement, which really similar to the known label document, namely Financial Report.

Can you help me suggest any better design flow to handle this multi-class document classification ? Thanks for your support !

Comment: It looks like there's simply no good indicator in the text to distinguish the known class vs. the unknown one. Would a human expert be able to distinguish them? If yes, try to represent the clues used by the expert as features. if no, it's just not doable.